# What does reciprocity mean?

Tags: meaning

> It should be said that the view from the Hurtigruten is very slow. As in: very, very slow. Despite once being billed as the “coastal express,” the ferry actually travels at a maximum speed of around 15 knots, which is about the speed of a brisk bicycle ride. So you really have time to linger on every skerry, every shoal, every wind-blown bluff.
>   [Scroll 40% down the website] The slowness of the Hurtigruten forced all of us into a relationship of **reciprocity** with the landscape. Despite being only 150,000 square miles (about the size of Montana), the country boasts one of the most undulatory coastlines in the world, measuring an astonishing 64,000 miles (by comparison, the entire United States coastline measures 95,471 miles).

How can a traveller and the landscape be related by [reciprocity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reciprocity?q=RECIProcity)?

http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/09/19/travel/reif-larsen-norway.html?smid=tw-nytimes&_r=0

Answer (score 1):

Basically a two way beneficial relationship between man and the environment.

See this definition - [reciprocity](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/reciprocity) sense 1:

> 1) reciprocal state or relationship; mutual action, dependence, etc.

The ferry goes slow so you can appreciate the landscape. Then presumably the coastal area would benefit as fewer people would want to spoil the natural environment.

Answer (score 0):

I would offer a different interpretation that the (7 years previous...) answer. The mutual relationship between the landscape and the travelers is one of appreciation, but has nothing to do with "not wanting to spoil the natural environment".

"Reciprocity" carries a specific meaning in relationship to observation, derived from an artistic concept that art is *offering* itself to the viewer; in return, the viewer *offers* their attention & appreciation. [(Source)](https://lucian.uchicago.edu/blogs/mediatheory/keywords/reciprocity/) In general, the more passive the art medium (e.g.: paintings instead of video games), the more attention the enjoyer must lend to appreciate it fully, and the more reciprocal the artistic relationship.

Generally, while traveling at high speed, the traveler is unable to appreciate the landscape in an artistic sense. The author of your excerpt is implying that not only are travelers able to appreciate the landscape through which they travel, they are able to do so to such an extent that an artistic relationship is formed between them. This is enabled by the slow pace of travel.